# Cannot Linking. openURL whatsup message in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, whatsapp

I need to open whatsup with a preloaded message, like this:

```
Linking.openURL('whatsapp://send?text==%C2%A1Hola!%20Quiero%20realizar%20una%20consulta.&phone=5493416931539').catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

I receive the error message: `"{"framestopop:1,code:EUNSPECIFIED"}"`

I've tried with `.catch(() => null);` but doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the below code

```
import { Linking } from ‘react-native’;
shareToWhatsAppWithContact = (text, phoneNumber) => {
 Linking.openURL(`whatsapp://send?text=${text}&phone=${phoneNumber}`);
}
```