# cannot navigate between views in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Login from './src/screens/Login';
import Secured from './src/screens/Secured';
import NewPass from './src/screens/NewPass';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store'; //Import the store

class ReactNativeStormpath extends Component {

    state = {
      isLoggedIn: false      
    }

    render() {

      if (this.state.isLoggedIn) 
        return ( 
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Secured 
              onLogoutPress={() => this.setState({isLoggedIn: false})}
            />
          </Provider>
        )
      else 
        return (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Login 
                onLoginPress={() =>  this.props.navigation.navigate('NewPass')}
            />
          </Provider>
        )
    }  
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativeStormpath', () => ReactNativeStormpath);
```

I receive "undefined is not an object", or the button doesn´t do anything,
i've followed almost all post and couldn't find a way to navigate between views in react native, this can't be that difficult.

Comment: To be able to navigate you need to have a navigation structure via a library or a custom one. Do you have such implementation?

Comment: i've followed: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html
I don't have an "App" class, like: "export default class App", i don't know where to add the "const RootStack = createStackNavigator("

Comment: Then please update your question showing that your navigation stack

Comment: @bennygenel i've updated my previous comment

Comment: When you create your project initially you should have 2 files. `index.js` and `app.js`. You should edit your `app.js` file and add navigation stack to there as it shows in tutorial.

Comment: i don't have an App.js file, i've created the project follow this: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-react-native-example?utm_source=syndicate&utm_campaign=scotchio-feb2017&utm_medium=post

Comment: That is a year old project which has an outdated file structure. You should use a more resent version of a starter project

Comment: oh i see. thanks. I've also posted this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928633/cannot-linking-openurl-whatsup-message-in-react-native?noredirect=1#comment88856237_50928633
May be you can help too. thanks!!!